# What's the most efficient way to maintain a lineTo between two points in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance, drawing, rendering

I'm looking to work out the most efficient way to maintain the joining of two points with a line in AS3. Basically, I have a whole bunch of circles that move around, and have a property `subNode` which will act as an end point for the line.

At the moment, the way I'm doing it is extremely intensive:

```
if(_line != null) _line.parent.removeChild(_line);

_line = new Sprite();
_line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xE1164B);
_line.graphics.lineTo(subNode.x - x, subNode.y - y);

addChild(_line);
```

Is there maybe just a `redrawLine()` or something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to instantiate a Sprite every time. Also a `Shape` should be enough in this case.

```
if(_line == null) {
   _line = addChild(new Shape()) as Shape;
}

_line.graphics.clear();
_line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xE1164B);
_line.graphics.lineTo(subNode.x - x, subNode.y - y);
```

Also you should think about when to draw the line. Maybe only if the subNode hase moved. But there is not enough code for a proper answer to that.

Comment: My bad, that is actually the case - but it was still quite slow.

Comment: Well, it runs in a step method that I've defined within Node - all instances of Node are added to an Array within NodeHandler which is iterated through using for each() and calling step on each result. Overall the performance was perfect - just the lineTo() issue was throwing it off.

Comment: Here's what the result was, for interests sake. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8216991/nodes.swf